# Hostmonster SMTP credentials are not working on node application hosted on digital ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, smtp, digital-ocean, nodemailer, hostmonster

I've a domain purchased from hostmonster and node.js application hosted on the digital ocean droplet. I am using the smtp configurations in my node application with nodemailer module and not receiving the emails on any account. I've used gmail smtp settings and they are working perfect but support@cuufy.com smtp settings are not working in my node.js application.

Note: (I've tried the smtp settings on outlook and mail client roundcube and it's working fine there).

Here are my smtp settings:

```
const config={
       host:'mail.cuufy.com',
       pool: true,
       tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
       },
       auth: {
           user:'support@cuufy.com',
           pass:'password'
       },
        port: 26
     };
```

I've also attached Mail client settings in the attachment.

[image]

Help in this regard will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Any entries in the log ? Also, you got `port: 26` but SMTP is normally on port 25, maybe that's it?

Comment: I've checked the logs there is no as such error in it and tried both 465 and 25 ports as well they are not working.

Comment: Are you sure that mail.cuufy.com is the right host name? Don't you need to use a Hostmonster host?

Comment: Yes, mail.cuufy.com is the right host name. I've also attached mail client settings as well.

Comment: Have you tried port `465` with the flag `tls` set as `true`? Also, you can use the `verify` function to check your settings before trying to email: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/ bottom of the page

Comment: I've tried that as well, and verify function is returning success: Server is ready to take our messages